# Вывод: мы это сделали(,) и это было очень весело таки

Tags: пунктуация

Можете, пожалуйста, мне сказать, нужна ли вон та запятая? Я сомневаюсь, так как есть общее предложение - "Вывод" - которое, как я понимаю, оба остальных предложения связывает-таки.

1. Вывод: мы это сделали(,) и это было очень весело таки.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец да, прошу прощения, поспешил. Сейчас переделаю комментарий.

Comment: Орфографическая правка: частица "таки" пишется через дефис после наречий, а также глаголов и других частиц: *"весело-таки"*. Но раздельно в препозиции: *"таки весело"*.

Comment: @Cius Отлично! Тогда верхние комментарии удаляем.

Comment: Частица *пожалуйста* есть атрибут просьбы, употребляется и в ответах на просьбу, но не в вопросах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пунктуация зависит от того, рассматриваете ли вы *"вывод"* как общий элемент для двух простых предложений в составе последующего ССП или хотите показать, что *"вывод"* ко второму (*"это было очень весело-таки"*) не относится.